# MySQL query optimization with group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I want to calculate total and unique clickouts based on country,partner and retailer.
I have achieved the desired result but i think its not a optimal solution and for longer data sets it will take longer time. how can I improve this query?
here is my test table, designed query and expected output:

```
"country_id","partner","retailer","id_customer","id_clickout"
"1","A","B","100","XX"
"1","A","B","100","XX"
"2","A","B","100","XX"
"2","A","B","100","GG"
"2","A","B","100","XX"
"2","A","B","101","XX"

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x AS
SELECT test1.country_id, test1.partner,test1.retailer, test1.id_customer, 
SUM(CASE WHEN test1.id_clickout IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS clicks,
CASE WHEN test1.id_clickout IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS unique_clicks
FROM test1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
;
SELECT country_id,partner,retailer, SUM(clicks), SUM(unique_clicks)
FROM x
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

**Output:**

```
"country_id","partner","retailer","SUM(clicks)","SUM(unique_clicks)"
"1","A","B","2","1"
"2","A","B","4","2"
```

And here is DDL and input data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 country_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 partner VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 retailer VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 id_customer BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 id_clickout VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL)
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'A','B','100','XX'),(1,'A','B','100','XX'),
            (2,'A','B','100','XX'),(2,'A','B','100','GG'),
            (2,'A','B','100','XX'),(2,'A','B','101','xx')
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Are you using the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x AS ...` just as an example, or are you actually using that in your code?  If so, you're losing all indexing of the data, making the second aggregation slower.  How many records do you expect to be written to the temp table?  Could you use nested queries instead?  What do you expect `CASE WHEN test1.id_clickout IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS unique_clicks` to be doing? *(It's neither an aggregate nor part of the `GROUP BY`, so MySQL will return the result from **one row** arbitrarily chosen from the group.)*

Comment: I will use this temporary table in code and by unique_clicks I want to get only one id_clickout per id_customer. e.g. if a same customer makes multiple clicks i just want one. Records can be one million

Comment: Not sure it will make much difference, but will certainly be nicer on the eye - `SUM(CASE WHEN test1.id_clickout IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` is exactly the same as `COUNT(test1.id_clickout)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  country_id,
  partner,
  retailer,
  COUNT(id_clickout)   AS clicks,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id_clickout IS NOT NULL THEN id_customer END) AS unique_clicks
FROM
  test1
GROUP BY
  1,2,3
;
```

`COUNT(a_field)` won't count any `NULL` values.

So, `COUNT(id_clickout)` will only count the number of times that it is `NOT NULL`.

Equally, the `CASE WHEN` statement in the `unique_clicks` only returns the `id_customer` for records where they clicked, otherwise it returns `NULL`.  This means that the `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE)` only counts distinct customers, and only when they clicked.

**EDIT :**

I just realised, it's potentially even simpler than that...

```
SELECT
  country_id,
  partner,
  retailer,
  COUNT(*)                    AS clicks,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_customer) AS unique_clicks
FROM
  test1
WHERe
  id_clickout IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  1,2,3
;
```

The only material difference in the results will be that any `country_id, partner, retailed` that previously showed up with `0 clicks` will now not appear in the results at all.

With an INDEX on `country_id, partner, retailed, id_clickout, id_customer` or `country_id, partner, retailed, id_customer, id_clickout`, however, this query should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT country_id,partner,retailer,COUNT(retailer) as `sum(clicks)`,count(distinct id_clickout) as `SUM(unique_clicks)`
FROM test1
GROUP BY country_id,partner,retailer
```

Result:

```
COUNTRY_ID  PARTNER  RETAILER  SUM(CLICKS)  SUM(UNIQUE_CLICKS)
1           A        B         2            1
2           A        B         4            2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21542f/7).

Comment: I believe that this will return incorrect results.  See my answer for a similar approach with different business logic.